# Materialize Modal is not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Hello I'm using Materialize js and its modal is not opening follwing is my code.Please let me know what wrong with it?

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal bottom-sheet">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>
            Modal Header
        </h4>
        <p>
            A bunch of text
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rushil_pachchigar/1p63g3ot/)

Comment: Could it be that it isn't ready on `$(document).ready()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Javascript add this: $('#modal1').modal();
before:  $('#modal1').modal('open');

Comment: Okay its working fine Now I want stop click event expect modal. How can i prvent?

Comment: The modal is only closing when you click on the overlay background, not on the modal itself. If you dont want that, change:

$('#modal1').modal(); 

to:

$('#modal1').modal({dismissible: false});